# Create 'heat map' from GPS data in matlab

Tags: matlab, dictionary, gps, heat

I have a bunch of GPS-data from a soccer game (as a referee). I would like to create a heat map, so that it is clear where you spent most of the time in the field. So this means a red color when there are a lot of dots close to each other and blue color when there are no dots or the dots are far from each other.

Someone an idea how to do this in Matlab?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: You can first transform your (x,y) coordinates into a matrix using `accumarray(index, values)`  and then plot the matrix using `imagesc`. But you may `round` your (x,y)  data first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [dscatter](http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8430-flow-cytometry-data-reader-and-visualization/content/dscatter.m) file written by Robert Henson.

Sample example:

```
addpath(genpath('../src_plot'));

X = randn(1000,1);
Y = randn(1000,1);

dscatter(X, Y, 'plottype', 'image');
colormap('jet')
```

You can use `'surf'`, `'mesh'`, `'contour'` instead of image according to what you expect.

[image]

Comment: Thanx! This brings me a step further.